# C code in Eclipse return undefined reference to symbol cvSaveImage

Tags: c, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt, opencv3.0

I'm using Eclipse and OpenCV (Version 3) on Ubuntu 15.10 to write a C program but I don't get why I'm always getting the error

```
undefined reference to symbol 'cvSaveImage'
```

If I run

```
pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs
```

I get

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
-lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres
-lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d 
-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video 
-lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann 
-lopencv_core -lopencv_hal
```

So I added the LIbraries to the GCC C Liker as in the image below

[image]

If I don't try to use the function cvSaveImage the program runs, so the other libraries correctly work. I included the highgui library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvSaveImage` belongs to [opencv_imgcodecs](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0a/group__imgcodecs__c.html#gadb5ed24070a0032732c602b5d234ad5b).

You are missing `opencv_imgcodecs` in the libraries (-l).

Comment: Now it works, thank you. I thought it was part of highgui: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html